# Transact SQL - Join one table with other two

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that is for PaymentRequest (PR), each PR table has two forms of pay, a WorkProgress, and a AdvanceByWarranty, the relation is like this:

[image: Data model]

I Need to create a report to get all the payment made in that (PR), and some other fields between them

The sql that I was using to join PaymentRequest with WorkProgress is this, and it works, it returns the WorkProgress of that payment

[image: WorkProgress]

To get the Advances by warranty I use this, it also works, returns 2 Advances, as it should be

[image: AdvanceByWarranty]

But, when I mix both, it doesnt return 3 rows, as it should be, it returns two. The result is this

[image: Both]

I was expecting something like this (With shorter names)

[image: ExpectedQuery]

How can i get the expected query?

Edit:

The sql to get the expected query is this

```sql
select 
pr.ProjectId, pr.NumberPaymentState, 
wp.ToCollectAmmount as WPAmmount, wp.ToCollectPercent as WPPercent,
null as AWAmmount, null as AWPercent
from PaymentRequests pr
left join WorkProgresses wp on (wp.ProjectId = pr.ProjectId and wp.NumberPaymentState = pr.NumberPaymentState)

union all

select 
pr.ProjectId, pr.NumberPaymentState, 
null as WPAmmount, null as WPPercent,
aw.ToCollectAmmount as AWAmmount, aw.ToCollectPercent as AWPercent
from PaymentRequests pr
left join AdvanceByWarranties aw on (aw.ProjectId = pr.ProjectId and aw.NumberPaymentState = pr.NumberPaymentState)
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: All these images of text really deter from the question here. Take the time to post the data in a consumable format (and don't post the code as both `text` and an image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have wanted what you show, but it doesn't work like this.

Just use `UNION ALL` between your first two queries, and rename the columns accordingly. Here is some pseudocode hybrid to guide you:

```
select keycols, workercols, null as advancecols
from pr join worker

union all

select keycols, null as workercols, advancecols
from pr join advancecols
```

Comment: It works, in case that someone needs the SQL for a more concrete example, i put at the end